# Mac shortcut to place window in secondary screen?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, display, shortcuts

Does anyone know if there is a keyboard shortcut to move a window to a secondary screen under OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native way to do this in OSX, but [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/) has this feature.

Comment: It seems the best solution for this is SizeUp: http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/